# How to start RMI Registry through java code?

Tags: java, client, rmi, rmiregistry

I have written java programs for Client and Server. But, to run the program I need to start rmi registry manually! How to start RMI registry through java code (through Server)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port)`.  See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html#createRegistry%28int%29).

Comment: Used LocateRegistry.createRegistry(6302); not working i m getting Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.x.x;

Comment: @Andy No, you're not. Either you're not calling `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(),` or you're not getting that exception when you do. I suspect you're getting that exception *in your client.*

Comment: I wrote this in server! I want RMI registry to be started when the server executes!

Comment: @Andy `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` cannot possibly throw 'connection refused'. It doesn't try to create any connections. You are omitting some vital information here.

Comment: @Aniket what happened in the end?

Answer (score -1):

First, you need execute in java bin folder "start rmiregistry" throught shell/command line (create CLASSPATH system var to java class/jar to the project to register in RMI Register, RMI Registry need know their classes).

Before you can use LocateRegistry.getRegistry().