# How to run Java SE 6 with RMI commands on Windows with Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, command-line, rmi

I have a Windows machine with Eclipse and I've been given the following instructions:

> i) run
>
> /usr/java/latest/bin/rmiregistry &
>
> to enable RMI registration;
>
> ii) run
>
> java -classpath poi-3.7-20101029.jar: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 >comp34120.ex2.Main &
>
> to run the GUI of the platform;
>
> iii) run
>
> java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 SimpleLeader &
>
> to run the SimpleLeader.
>
> And after these steps, you can play with the GUI to get some ideas of how the >platform works.

How can I run these commands on my machine?

Comment: ...by running them?  I'm not sure I understand the question...

Comment: you  don't have to do all these.  In eclipse first run your server program ( wait till the server start) , then run your client program.  note: you don't need to start RMI registry manually. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/10447357/3852345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` at the end is Linux for `START`.

```
SET "PATH=C:\path\to\java6\bin;%PATH%"

START rmiregistry

START java -classpath poi-3.7-20101029.jar;. -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 comp34120.ex2.Main

START java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 SimpleLeader
```

The first line is only needed if not there already, i.e. first in PATH.

Comment: @dilly The `java` command doesn't return until the program ends, so `START` is needed to run them both. Edit rejected.